# Equation of a plane containing a point and a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

Find the equation of the plane containing the point (0, 7, -7) and the line

$\frac{x+1}{-3} = \frac{y-3}{2} = \frac{z+2}{1}$

I'm not sure how to tackle this question, since the equation of the line is given in the Cartesian form and not in the vector form.

(Not homework- I am preparing for an exam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set $P(-1,+3,-2)$, $Q(0,7,-7)$ and $\vec{v}(-3,2,1)$ is the leading vector of the line(the expression multiplied by a parameter to form the locus for a line), so you can find the normal vector to the plane as follows: $$\vec{PQ}\times\vec{v}=\begin{vmatrix} i & j & k\\ -1 & -4 & 5\\ -3 &2 &1 \end{vmatrix}=-14i-14k-14j$$ So the equation of the plane would be: $$\mathscr{P}:-14(x-0)-14(y-7)-14(z+7)=0$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the steps needed to obtain the equation of the plane in the form of a(x-x')+b(y-y')+c(z-z')=0?

Comment: @17andLearning: First we need a normal vector for the plane. Do the above cross product to fin out its components. Assume that $\vec{PQ}\times\vec{v}=(a,b,c)$ so the equation of the plane will be $a(x-x_Q)+b(y-y_Q)+c(z-z_Q)=0$.

Comment: What would be the equation of PQ in this case?

Comment: @17andLearning: $(x_P-x_Q,y_P-y_Q,y_P-y_Q )$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, is y-x-z=14 the correct equation for the plane?

Comment: @17andLearning: I edited the post.